# Enum with switch in Swift

Tags: enums, swift, switch-statement

I'm trying to loop over all tab items to set some properties through a switch using enum:

```
enum TabItems {
    case FirstTab
    case SecondTab
    case ThirdTab
}
```

Here's my loop:

```
for item in self.tabBar.items {
    switch item.tag {
    case .FirstTab:
        println("first tab")
    default:
        println("tab not exists")
    }
}
```

There is an error: `Enum case 'FirstTab' not found in type 'Int!'`. How do I properly use enum in this switch statement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're getting the error because `item.tag` is declared as an `Int` (`NSInteger` in the API originally) but you're trying to compare it to your `TabItems` enumeration. You can either use `Int` values in your `switch` statement:

```
for item in self.tabBar.items {
    switch item.tag {
    case 0:
        println("first tab")
    case 1:
        println("second tab")
    default:
        println("not recognized")
    }
}
```

Or you can convert the tag to your `enum`, like the example below. (Note that you'll need to update your enumeration's declaration to support `.fromRaw()`.)

```
enum TabItems : Int {
    case FirstTab = 0
    case SecondTab
    case ThirdTab
}

for item in self.tabBar.items {
    if let tabItem = TabItems.fromRaw(item.tag) {
        switch tabItem {
        case .FirstTab:
            println("first tab")
        case .SecondTab:
            println("second tab")
        default:
            println("not recognized")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 2.1 has the following syntax `if let tabItem = TabItems(rawValue: item.tag) {`